# Python - Crypto.Cipher/Pycrypto on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, pycrypto

After a bit of googling around, I see this issue is pretty common but has no direct answers.
Trying to use Pycrypto on my Mac 10.8.5. Installed it through Pip, Easy_install, and manually with setup.py yet when I try to import it, it says it can't find the module.

Anyone else have an issue like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those having this issue on Mac, for something reason Pip, easy_install, and even doing it manually installs Crypto with a lowercase 'c' in to site-packages. By browsing in to site-packages and renaming 'crypto' to 'Crypto', it solves the issues with other libaries.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent ages trying to work out what was going on, turned out I was having exactly this issue

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, and this is because you probably have different versions of Python. So, in fact, the package is installed, but for a separate version. What you need to do is see which executable file is linked to when `python` or `pip` is called.